# Can I import an outline into powerpoint

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2007, outline

I would like to create a bullet point powerpoint in a text file (or Word document) and then import it into Powerpoint 2007

```
Slide 1 title
 - bullet 1
 - bullet 2
    - subpoint
 - bullet 3
Slide 2 title
 - bullet 1
 - bullet 2
```

I find that powerpoint makes one think too much about form to the exclusion of content.

Answers of the form *Don't use Powerpoint* might not go down to well with our corporate presentation style police !

Comment: Why not directly create the text outline in PowerPoint's "Outline" view?

Comment: @sblair - have briefly tried that but I am tempted to look too much at the presentation side.  I find it helpful to step away from Powerpoint.  Pehaps should give it another try

Answer (score 2):

Go to the New Slide button on the Home tab. Click the drop down arrow.

At the bottom you'll see "Slide from Outline"

Clicking that will direct you to your file system where you can find the document with the outline. It automatically creates slides for the major points and puts second level text as bullets.