# Import formatted text from Word into PowerPoint

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, import, microsoft-word-2011, master

I understand the basics of importing an Word outline into PowerPoint. I want to know how to import the text blocks into pre-styled text boxes that have been positioned on the slide to a specific layout. When I create these boxes on a master slide, the import function ignores them and creates new text boxes on top of the pre-styled boxes. I'm using Office:Mac 2011.

Comment: See also https://superuser.com/q/130605/74576